# Create new table from Existing table With out identity property to be copied

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using `select * into` to create a table from another table and used `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` for newly created table to accept data including identity column.

Now my question is that Is there any way to create a table (say TABLE A) from another existing table (say TABLE B) with out copying identity property of TABLE B to TABLE A.

Comment: What should TABLE A eventually look like? Should it end up with no IDENTITY column? Should it have a different IDENTITY column? Should it have the same IDENTITY column but with different values?

Comment: Table A should have the identity column of TABLE B i.e only column should present with out identity property. IF Column1 is the identity column in TABLE B then TABLE A Shoud have that column with out identity property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, let's say `TABLEA` looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLEA (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    Column1 VARCHAR(50)
)
```

and let's assume that `TABLEB` looks the same. If we wanted to move data from `TABLEB` into `TABLEA` without moving the identity column we would write this statement:

```
INSERT INTO TABLEA (Column1)
    SELECT Column1 FROM TABLEB
```

and this will cause every new row in `TABLEA` to get its own identity value.

But note, you can't issue a `SELECT * FROM TABLEB` because that would also select the `ID` column. You have to list out all of the fields you want individually. However, generally speaking, I think a lot of very experienced DBA's and programmers would say that `SELECT * FROM Table` is really dangerous because if the schema changes everything breaks. You really want to ***always*** be specific.

Comment: But i have to perform this operation on many tables and so i am not interested to mention columns list in select statement (I simply want to write INSERT INTO TABLEA SELECT * FROM TABLE B).

Comment: @SanthoshRamini, you can't do that because you ***don't want the identity column*** and `SELECT * FROM Table` will ***recover the identity column***.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + c.name FROM sys.columns c where c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.TABLE_NAME') and c.is_identity <> 1 FOR XML PATH('')),1, 2, '') AS CSVColumn

This will give you a comma separated list of columns of each table. Copy these statements into notepad to create a script that you can run.